# C/C++ Inline coercion of array of pointers (void**)

Tags: c++, c, initializer-list, coercion

I am using a library function that expects an array of pointers (`void**`) at some point, it works more or less like this.

```
void* args[] = { &var_a, &var_b, &var_c, ... };
someFunction(args);
```

After using it once, I would like to call the same function again, so what I do is create another variable like:

```
void* args_2[] = { &var_d, &var_e, &var_f, ... };
someFunction(args_2);
```

And so on ...

I would like to find a way to *recycle* the `args` symbol, so I don't have to do args_2, args_3, args_4 every time I call it; but when I try to reassign it like:

```
args = { &var_d, &var_e, &var_f, ... };
```

I get the following:

```
error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

I understand the error but I don't know how to avoid it or coerce this thing into the intended array of pointers type.

I know they are two different languages, but I am looking for a solution that works in both C and C++.

Comment: C or C++?  There is a difference.

Comment: I could accept an answer that works in both scenarios. Also, @NathanOliver could you tell me more about what could be different?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<void *>`, that *does* support construction from an initializer list. Use as `someFunction(args.data());`

Comment: If you want solutions for both C or C++, I suggest asking two separate questions, as the solutions are inherently different (C can do things C++ can't and vice versa). If you don't care, then I recommend just sticking with one language. Roll a dice if you must, but I suggest C++ as you can simply use std::vector

Comment: Alternatively, make a block for the call: `{ void* args[] = { ... }; someFunction(args) }`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. No, std::vector<...> is out of the question. I am looking for a way to somehow 'cast' the initializer_list type into the correct void**, as it is somehow already happening in the initial declaration.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I do not want two solutions :) if you read my comment carefully I am pointing to /one/ single solution that could work both on C and C++.

Comment: @almosnow that's pretty unwieldy. How do you even intend to use such a polyglot in your real use-case?

Comment: If it works in C it should work in C++, in principle ... (I know...)

Comment: @almosnow well, no, that's a myth. kiran's answer is C-only, and mine is C++-only (even if you use `typedef`). What now?

Answer (score 3):

Why use a local variable at all, if you only need it once to call `someFunction`?

```
using args = void *[];

someFunction(args{&a, &b});
someFunction(args{&a, &b, &c});
```

Alternatively, C++ify this a bit more with a wrapper:

```
template <class... T>
decltype(auto) someFunction(T *... args) {
    void *args_[] { args... };
    return someFunction(args_);
}

someFunction(&a, &b);
someFunction(&a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I'm just testing it quickly, will be back at this.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of compound literals as below with pointer to pointer.

```
void** args = (void *[]){ &var_a, &var_b, &var_c, ... };

args = (void *[]){ &var_d, &var_e, &var_f, ... };
```

Comment: Thank Kiran! In spirit I am looking for something like this, however, it does not compile: due to "error: taking address of temporary array". Which I understand as well, hmm, how could this be avoided?

Comment: @almosnow this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941846/c-error-taking-address-of-temporary-array.