# memcpy - taking the address of temporary array error

Tags: c++, arduino, memcpy

I am working on Arduino and trying to change the elements of an array. Before setup, I initialized the array like this:

```
bool updateArea[5] = { false };
```

And then I wanted to change the array like this:

```
updateArea[0] => false,
updateArea[1] => true,
updateArea[2] => false,
updateArea[3] => false,
updateArea[4] => true
```

by using:

```
memcpy(&updateArea[0], (bool []) {false, true, false, false, true}, 5);
```

However, I get the "taking address of temporary array" error.

I also tried to initialize the array in setup and loop functions but get the same error.

Comment: Arduino is not in C. It's in C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ error: "taking address of temporary array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941846/c-error-taking-address-of-temporary-array)

Comment: @KamilCuk, is this different in C?

Comment: @Juraj Yes, this code compiles in C but not in C++.

Comment: what is your compiler? "compound literals" are **not** temporaries but rather unnamed local/global variables. Is it a compiler bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of syntax is valid in C, but not in C++ - which is the language underlying the Arduino IDE.

But you have a few easy solutions:

- Since you're willing to write out the array anyways, why not just:

  ```
  bool updateArea[5] = {false, true, false, false, true};
  ```
- You can declare the array as a **non-temporary** array and then pass it to `memcpy`:

  ```
  static const bool newArray[5] = {false, true, false, false, true};
  memcpy(updateArea, newArray, sizeof(updateArea));
  ```
- If you can assume that `sizeof(bool) == 1`, then you can use this hacky solution:

  ```
  memcpy(updateArea, "\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01", sizeof(updateArea));
  ```

  which will copy the bytes directly.

Comment: probably better to declare newArray as `static const` so the code generation is (presumably) more efficient. Otherwise the compiler may initialize this temporary variable every time the function is called and then copy it